# Array size 0 in adapter > 0 in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview

Well this is very strange thing that happen to me.. I have an ArrayAdapter where the size of `data` value result in the logcat = 0. So this array seems empty. I try to insert in the MainActivity, where i add my item at the list, the condition to see the array size that result  > 0. I need that this array is equal at another array infact the condition is:

```
if (titoli.size() > data.size())
                Log.w("Array compare", "Titoli > Data!"+ " " + titoli.size() + " " + data.size());
```

And the result is `Titoli > Data 48 38` in the MainActivity and `Titoli > Data 48 0` in the adapter!! So the list crash!! To bypass this problem i created this condition:

```
if (this.data.size() > 0){
            cache.dateArticoli.setText(data.get(pos));
        }
```

Now the Activity starts without crashes but the `data` appears only when i begin to scroll the list and when i arrive at the end of the list i have the crash with this logcat:

```
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400): Process: it.dd.multiplayerit, PID: 19400
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 33, size is 33
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at it.dd.multiplayerit.ParsingArrayAdapter.getView(ParsingArrayAdapter.java:97)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4247)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-23 16:42:16.955: E/AndroidRuntime(19400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

I can't understand why!

at line 97:

```
cache.dateArticoli.setText(data.get(pos));
```

Comment: adapter is an element on the main activity or in a child fragment? Where you initialize it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is is the size of the list is 33 and you are accessing data.get(33)

Accessing the list should be below the list size.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 33, size is 33
```

I think Need to do this one too

```
if (this.data.size() > 0 && pos < this.data.size()){
      cache.dateArticoli.setText(data.get(pos));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start at `0` so try

```
this.data.size()-1
```

Comment: where have i to do this?